# Execute an external program from an android app

Tags: java, android-studio, error-handling, external-process

I need to execute 'nmap' binary for my app. I use the wrapper nmap4j, in which i write the path on the device "sdcard/Nmap/bin/nmap".

```java
try {
    nmap4j.execute();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error execute " + e);
}
```

The following error :
        error execute org.nmap4j.core.nmap.NMapExecutionException: Cannot run program "sdcard/Nmap/bin/nmap": error=13, Permission denied

showed up, and the app crashes because of a null pointer exception later

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution to THIS problem.

I used the Android Studio "Device File Explorer", and I uploaded my binay executable in the application data folder:

root/data/data/com.example.appname/

Hope it can help